# How to store the results of each iteration of for loop in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
cols = Germandata.columns
percentage_list = [0.05,0.01,0.1]
for i in range(len(Germandata)) :
    for percentage in percentage_list:
        columns_n = 3
        random_columns = np.random.choice(cols, columns_n, replace=False)
        local_data = Germandata.copy()
        remove_n = int(round(local_data.shape[0] * percentage, 0))
        for column_name in random_columns:
            drop_indices = np.random.choice(local_data.index, remove_n, replace=False)
            local_data.loc[drop_indices, column_name] = np.nan
```

The code here selects the columns at random and will delete certain percentage of observations from the data and it will replace them with NANs. The problem here is after running the loop i will get the final percentage deleted dataframe in the percentage list because it is overwriting after each iteration. How to store the  dataframe with nans after each iteration.? Ideally i should get three dataframes with different percent of data deleted.

Comment: please provide the sample data

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df_list = []
cols = Germandata.columns
percentage_list = [0.05,0.01,0.1]
for percentage in percentage_list:
    columns_n = 3
    random_columns = np.random.choice(cols, columns_n, replace=False)
    local_data = Germandata.copy()
    remove_n = int(round(local_data.shape[0] * percentage, 0))
    for column_name in random_columns:
        drop_indices = np.random.choice(local_data.index, remove_n, replace=False)
        local_data.loc[drop_indices, column_name] = np.nan
        local_data['percentage'] = percentage # optional
    df_list.append(local_data)
df_05 = df_list[0]
df_01 = df_list[1]
df_1 = df_list[2]
```

Alternatively, you can use a dictionary

```
df_dict = {}
cols = Germandata.columns
percentage_list = [0.05,0.01,0.1]
for percentage in percentage_list:
    columns_n = 3
    random_columns = np.random.choice(cols, columns_n, replace=False)
    local_data = Germandata.copy()
    remove_n = int(round(local_data.shape[0] * percentage, 0))
    for column_name in random_columns:
        drop_indices = np.random.choice(local_data.index, remove_n, replace=False)
        local_data.loc[drop_indices, column_name] = np.nan
        local_data['percentage'] = percentage # optional
    df_dict[str(percentage)] = local_data
df_05 = df_dict['0.05']
df_01 = df_dict['0.01']
df_1 = df_dict['0.1']
```

Comment: It creates a list with data of three different percentages but how to convert them three different data frames?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by convert. Do you want to create three data frame objects?

Comment: Yes, i want to create three dataframe objects

Comment: I edited my answer to include code you could use to define the three data frame objects. Does that answer your question?